# Appropriate Golang API timing measurement

Tags: rest, go, http

given an API client/server couple written in Go, I need to measure the overall API duration on the client side, the main goal is to include network transmission time in the measurement and be sure to not accidentally include any time consuming client operation.
Provided the two following pieces of code for client and server handler:

```
func clientRequest() {
    client := http.Client{Timeout: 30 * time.Second}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("get", "http://...", nil)

    start := time.Now()
    res, _ := client.Do(req)
    elapsedBeforeBodyRead := time.Since(start) 
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    elapsedAfterBodyRead := time.Since(start)
}

func serverRespond(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    start := time.Now()
    
    buf := make([]byte, 20*1024*1024)
    rand.Read(buf)
    payload := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)
    serverPayloadBuild := time.Since(start)
    partial = time.Now()

    // If no error, encode the body and the result code
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]interface{}{
        "payload":    payload,
    })
    serverTXtime := time.Since(partial)
    
    
    elapsedServer := time.Since(start)
}
```

I'm not understanding whether at the point where client records elapsedBeforeBodyRead (immediately after the client.Do) the body is already fully received client side or reception is completed after io.ReadAll(res.Body) call. Actually, the elapsedBeforeBodyRead is always lower than the elapsedServer. While the elapsedAfterBodyRead seems too much higher; especially when testing on localhost where I would expect a very low payload transfer time between processes.

Can anyone explain how the body transmission over underlying TCP is working with respect to client's Do and ReadAll functions and server's Encode function.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Following some comments I made additional investigation and report some data here. I moved the test on a couple of VMs to have higher resources as the localhost case was probably affected by resources shortage.

[image: API timings on VMs]

First column is server time to build the random payload. Azure bar is the client side request.Do timing; from my understanding, function returns immediately after header is received; so, it should be equivalent to server side payload creation plus JSON encoding at the beginning of json.NewEncoder(w).Encode plus header Tx time.

While the server continues to write data on output stream, the client's io.ReadAll keeps downloading until EOF is received.

Overall, if my understanding is correct the best timer to consider for overall API duration is elapsedAfterBodyRead on the client side.

What I'm still not sure about is the interpretation of the 25ms of additional time on the client side with respect to server's overall time.

Thanks for your comments

Comment: 2 things to consider: have you looked at the underlying source code (it's all open source after all), and secondly: have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: "the elapsedBeforeBodyRead is always lower than the elapsedServer" after request is made but before response is sent, the serve has to 1) generate a significant amount of random data; 2) base64 encode it, resulting in even *more* data.  Only then can it begin the process of encoding it to `w`.  "elapsedAfterBodyRead seems too much higher" this is a matter of opinion.  But you should add timers for how long the transfer took (`Encode(...)` call ) vs how long the entire server side took, you may be surprised at how little of that time is actually spent on the sending of the response.

Comment: Finally, if you want to talk about timeing, please include *actual numbers*.  It's hard to give a meaningful response which all we have to go in is "lower than" and "seems too much higher"

Comment: [1/2] `client.Do` connects to the server (but see below), sends the HTTP request to it, awaits the server's reponse, consumes its so-called status line and the header, if any, and returns control. The `Body` returned in the `http.Response` may be thought of as being positioned in the stream of data from the server right before the payload (the body). Note that 1) a typical TCP/IP stack implements buffering, so on a good network the first couple KBs of body may well be in the kernel's buffer (or even `net/http`s buffer, and/or both);

Comment: [2/2] 2) by default `http.Transport` which a client uses is configured to employ so-called "HTTP keep-alive" and tries to not close a connection used to carry out a request/response cycle, and rather place it in a pool of so-called "idle" connections. Another request to the same server (IP+port) done quickly enough for that connection to not expire, will not perform the connect + TCP handshake sequence (and TLS handshake, if you're using TLS).